# Is there a name for this type of plot? (function on complex plane vs time shown in 3D)

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions

I'm just looking for a name for this type of plot, which is time vs real part vs imaginary part shown as a space curve.

Complex exponential:

[image: complex sinusoid]

Used to explain chirplets:

[image]

Complex Morlet wavelet shown this way:

[image]

instead of being shown as two plots:

[image]

[image]

the original 1998 source of which just calls them "[complex analytical vibration signatures](https://books.google.com/books?id=1x_RvffW-hcC&lpg=PA710&ots=-12QJ6RDBU&dq=%22spectra%20and%20cepstra%20for%20two%20gearboxes%20are%20shown%22&pg=PA709#v=onepage&q=%22complex%20analytical%20vibration%20signatures%20of%20gears%22&f=false)".

Comment: I've seen the inverse of your situation, where a given space curve's projections on the coordinate planes are plotted along with the space curve itself, referred to as a "shadow plot".

Comment: Another example: http://www.pacifict.com/Examples/Gallery42.html "Complex functions of a real parameter

A complex function of a real parameter can be drawn as a curve in 3D."

Comment: Another example: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/st/Comparing_Analog_Digital_Complex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible name  is the **Heyser corkscrew** or the **generalized Heyser spiral**, at least for cisoids. It appears for instance in [The Analytic Impulse](http://andrewduncan.net/air/), Andrew Duncan,  JAES Volume 36 Issue 5 pp. 315-327; May 1988.

> A complex analytic function is to its real part as a solid object is
>   to its shadow. the analytic impulse $\Delta(t)$ is a complex
>   "function" whose real part is the familiar Dirac symbol $\delta(t)$.
>   This impulse finds application in energy-time calculations. The nature
>   of this impulse and its application to finding energy-time curves are
>   examined in the continuous, $z$-transform, and DFT domains. A simple
>   window is also discussed which leads to a smoother impulse
>   $\tilde{\Delta}(t)$

It seems fairly general:

> In a Heyser corkscrew this magnitude appears as the radial distance of
>   the central figure to the time

with a display of the Heyser corkscrew plot of `asinc(t)`

[image]

However, as asked in the SE.DSP question [3D wiggle plot for an analytic signal: Heyser corkscrew/spiral](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/29865/15892), I did not find a lot of authoritative traces so far.

Comment: FYI, the time projection is a cochleoid, but you probably knew that. It is not in the cissoid family.

Comment: There might be a misunderstanding: I use "cisoid"  (one s)  for the "complex exponential", and not "cissoid" (like the one from Diocles). Was that the reason of your comment (took me time to understand)?